# View inside curly braces not showing

Tags: react-native

I'm new in `ReactNative`. I'm following a tutorial from Udemy. I've been trying to show a value from a variable. its working in the instructor's video but not in my code. the code is given below:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        placeName: '',
        places: []
    }

    placeNameChangedHandler = val => {
        this.setState({
            placeName: val
        })
    }


    placeSubmitHandler = () => {
        if (this.state.placeName.trim() === "") {
            return;
        }

        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                places: prevState.places.concat(prevState.placeName)
            }
        })
    }

    render() {

        const placesOutput = this.state.places.map(place => {
            <Text>{place}</Text>
        })

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Type something"
                        style={styles.placeInput}
                        value={this.state.placeName}
                        onChangeText={this.placeNameChangedHandler}/>
                    <Button
                        style={styles.placeButton}
                        onPress={this.placeSubmitHandler}
                        title="Add"/>
                </View>
                <View>
                    {this.placesOutput}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

but the `{placeOutput}` is not showing anything. its working in the instructor's video but not in my code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't returning anything in your `map()` function. Your render function should look like this:

```
render() {

    const placesOutput = this.state.places.map(place => {
        return <Text>{place}</Text> //Added return statement
    })

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Type something"
                    style={styles.placeInput}
                    value={this.state.placeName}
                    onChangeText={this.placeNameChangedHandler}/>
                <Button
                    style={styles.placeButton}
                    onPress={this.placeSubmitHandler}
                    title="Add"/>
            </View>
            <View>
                {this.placesOutput}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

All I did was add a return statement in your `this.state.places.map()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much :) #Solved